# Django DecimalField Not Working

Tags: python, django

I am trying have a decimal field that can accept up to 8 digits and 3 decimal places but it keeps saying `Please enter a valid value. The nearest two valid values are 12345678 and 12345679.`

**model.py**

```
 daily_demand = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=3)
```

**forms.py**

```
daily_demand = forms.CharField(widget=forms.NumberInput())
```

Comment: You should use max_digits 11

Comment: @RajaSimon still not accepting the decimal points.

Comment: should it be `FloatField` other than `CharField` in your forms.py?

Comment: @HaifengZhang: Thank you. That was the problem. SOLVED!

Comment: @Yax glad it helps:)